# DocumentsCorePack condition fields not saving

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have been creating a DCP template to use with MS CRM. I have noticed there are two fields used at different situations called city and suburb. I need to create a conditional field to check these fields and display the one that is used.

{if "<>" = "" if "<>" = "" "" "<>" "<>"}

Now when I initially save the template and run Choose CRM Data, it works like a charm. HOWEVER, the moment I exit and reload the template, the conditional field is gone and now the fields do now show in the results at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you upload the template after your change? Or by save do you mean uploading the changed template to CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, in my opinion, is a bug. When you save the template to CRM it saves correctly, and works correctly. However if you open if, the conditional fields are gone. So basically you have to save it and trust its saved, then if you need to edit in the future, remember to put it back in.